# Rendering Host not opening in my local after taking latest XM Cloud repo

Tags: xm-cloud

I have download the latest repo from https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head and successfully created by local docker instance, but when I try to run

```
npm run start:connected
```

it throws the following error.

I ran

```
npm build
```

I'm using the latest node js version v21.6.1.

Please let me know if anyone already faced this kind of issue.

```
 D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter> npm run start:connected

> Testwebsite@21.6.0 start:connected
> npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel next:dev start:watch-components

ERROR: Cannot find module './typos.json'
Require stack:
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\read-pkg\index.js
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\npm-run-all\lib\read-package-json.js
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\npm-run-all\lib\index.js
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\npm-run-all\bin\npm-run-all\main.js
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\npm-run-all\bin\common\bootstrap.js
- D:\XM Cloud Latest repo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\npm-run-all\bin\npm-run-all\index.js
```

Comment: Hi All,

The issue is my node version is wrong, as per xmcloud.build.json file i should be using the below node version for rendering host.
"renderingHosts": {
  "xmcloudpreview": {
    "path": "./src/sxastarter",
    "nodeVersion": "20.10.0",
    "jssDeploymentSecret": "sssss",
    "enabled": true,
    "type": "sxa",
    "lintCommand": "lint",
    "startCommand": "start:production",
    "buildCommand": "build",
    "runCommand": "next:start"
  }
Thanks for the quick from from Sitecore Slack channel by @jflheureux

Comment: I converted the comment into an answer for the others. If you want, post it on your own as the answer and I will remove my answer as I'm not the one who came up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As OP wrote in their comment:

> The issue is my node version is wrong, as per `xmcloud.build.json` file I should be using the below node version for rendering host.

```
"renderingHosts": {
    "xmcloudpreview": {
        "path": "./src/sxastarter",
        "nodeVersion": "20.10.0",
        "jssDeploymentSecret": "sssss",
        "enabled": true,
        "type": "sxa",
        "lintCommand": "lint",
        "startCommand": "start:production",
        "buildCommand": "build",
        "runCommand": "next:start"
    }
```

Thanks for the quick answer from Sitecore Slack channel by @jflheureux